# gridview.extent doesn't scroll in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile-application

I've input a couple of cards in a gridview. But the scroll Bar doesn't work. There's a yellow-black striped box containing the message "Bottom overflowed by 129 pixels at the bottom of the screen.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
return Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, 
  children: <Widget>[
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
      child : Chip(
        label : Text("Topics", style: TextStyle(color : Colors.white, fontSize: 25), textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
        avatar: CircleAvatar(
          child: Icon(Icons.clear_all, color: Colors.white,),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue[800],
          ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[800], 
        ),
      ),
      GridView.extent(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        maxCrossAxisExtent: 200.0, 
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        primary: true,
        children: <Widget>[
          Card( 
            child : Container(
              constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(height: 0.3*screenHeight, width: 0.395*screenWidth),
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("background/music.jpg"),
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth
                ),
              ),
              child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                  left:0.0, bottom: 0.0,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, bottom: 5.0),
                    child: Text("#music", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.cyan[900] ,fontSize: 25.0, decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.wavy)),
                  )
                ),
                Positioned(
                  right:0.0, top: 0.0,
                  child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border), onPressed: (){int x =0;},),
              )
              ]
              )
            )
          ),
          Card( 
            child : Container(
              constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(height: 0.3*screenHeight, width: 0.395*screenWidth),
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("background/sports.jpg"),
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth
                ),
              ),
              child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                  left:0.0, bottom: 0.0,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, bottom: 5.0),
                    child: Text("#sports", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.cyan[900] ,fontSize: 25.0, decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.wavy)),
                  )
                ),
                Positioned(
                  right:0.0, top: 0.0,
                  child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border), onPressed: (){int x =0;},),
              )
              ]
              )
            )
          ),
          Card( 
            child : Container(
              constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(height: 0.3*screenHeight, width: 0.395*screenWidth),
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("background/business.jpg"),
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth
                ),
              ),
              child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                  left:0.0, bottom: 0.0,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, bottom: 5.0),
                    child: Text("#entrepreneurship", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.cyan[900] ,fontSize: 25.0, decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.wavy)),
                  )
                ),
                Positioned(
                  right:0.0, top: 0.0,
                  child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border), onPressed: (){int x =0;},),
              )
              ]
              )
            )
          ),
          Card( 
            child : Container(
              constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(height: 0.3*screenHeight, width: 0.395*screenWidth),
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("background/tech.jpg"),
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth
                ),
              ),
              child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                  left:0.0, bottom: 0.0,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, bottom: 5.0),
                    child: Text("#technology", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.cyan[900] ,fontSize: 25.0, decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.wavy)),
                  )
                ),
                Positioned(
                  right:0.0, top: 0.0,
                  child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border), onPressed: (){int x =0;},),
              )
              ]
              )
            )
          ),
          Card( 
            child : Container(
              constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(height: 0.3*screenHeight, width: 0.395*screenWidth),
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("background/health.png"),
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth
                ),
              ),
              child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                  left:0.0, bottom: 0.0,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, bottom: 5.0),
                    child: Text("#health", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.cyan[900] ,fontSize: 25.0, decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.wavy)),
                  )
                ),
                Positioned(
                  right:0.0, top: 0.0,
                  child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border), onPressed: (){int x =0;},),
              )
              ]
              )
            )
          ),
        ],
      )
  ],
);
```

}

Here's the output:
[image]
.....

Also, the error message says this:
Launching lib\main.dart on SM N900 in debug mode...
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
I/flutter ( 6092): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 6092): The following message was thrown during layout:
I/flutter ( 6092): A RenderFlex overflowed by 129 pixels on the bottom.
I/flutter ( 6092): The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
I/flutter ( 6092): The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and
I/flutter ( 6092): black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
I/flutter ( 6092): Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the
I/flutter ( 6092): RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
I/flutter ( 6092): This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
I/flutter ( 6092): seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a
I/flutter ( 6092): ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex,
I/flutter ( 6092): like a ListView.
I/flutter ( 6092): The specific RenderFlex in question is:
I/flutter ( 6092):   RenderFlex#7ae00 relayoutBoundary=up1 OVERFLOWING
I/flutter ( 6092):   creator: Column ← TopicsPage ← MediaQuery ← LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.body>] ←
I/flutter ( 6092):   CustomMultiChildLayout ← AnimatedBuilder ← DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ←
I/flutter ( 6092):   _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#2b99c ink renderer] ← NotificationListener ←
I/flutter ( 6092):   PhysicalModel ← AnimatedPhysicalModel ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 6092):   parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 81.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.body (can use size)
I/flutter ( 6092):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=360.0, 0.0<=h<=499.0)
I/flutter ( 6092):   size: Size(360.0, 499.0)
I/flutter ( 6092):   direction: vertical
I/flutter ( 6092):   mainAxisAlignment: start
I/flutter ( 6092):   mainAxisSize: max
I/flutter ( 6092):   crossAxisAlignment: stretch
I/flutter ( 6092):   verticalDirection: down
I/flutter ( 6092): ◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
I/flutter ( 6092): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
V/ActivityThread( 6092): updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{223f48d5 token=android.os.BinderProxy@24aeb760 {com.example.reachoutkefglobal/com.example.reachoutkefglobal.MainActivity}} show : true
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't scroll because it's wrapped into a `Column` which is not scrollable, and the error is because the `Column` has content that cannot be shown on the screen since it doesn't scroll.

For your design, you need to wrap all into a `ListView` and make the `GridView` not scrollable using `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`.

In your current code you could replace the `Column` for a `ListView`.

Comment: can you more elaborate, how to do it